# What's the difference between IPAddress.Any and IPAddress.IPv6Any fields?

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming

I tried the following code to make my code work in dual stack mode. Unfortunately, it's not opening port in the dual stack mode.

```
var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 2222);
listener.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.IPv6Only, 0);
listener.Start();
```

Later I realized that changing to `var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.IPv6Any, 2222);` would make it work for me. What exactly is the difference between

`IPAddress.Any` and `IPAddress.IPv6Any` fields?

[The documentation on MSDN is a bit vague](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.ipv6any.aspx)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`IPAddress.Any` is for all IPv4 interfaces, `IPAddress.IPv6Any` is for all IPv6 interfaces.

`IPAddress.Any` is `0.0.0.0`, `IPAddress.IPv6Any` is `::`

If you just use IPv6Any without using `SocketOptionName.IPv6Only` then you can accept both IPv4 and IPv6 connections on the same socket.

Comment: to make my code protocol agnost, can I use IPAddress.IPv6Any?

Comment: Are we sure theat using IPAddress.IPv6Any work with IPv4 and IPv6?

Comment: @Kiewic, yes. Try it yourself if you like :)

Comment: My test showed that `IPv6Any` does not cause the listener to bind to the IPv4 stack by default (i.e. specifying a socket option is required). For example, when I attempted to connect to 127.0.0.1, it failed. Note, that use of host names can cause confusion. For example, when I tried to connect to "localhost" it worked, but only after unsuccessfully trying 127.0.0.1 and then falling back to ::1.

Comment: If you want to use dual mode listener then and you are on .NET 4.5 use TcpListener.Create(port).  That's all you need to do.

Comment: To get this to work I had to add the SetSocketOption() line from @EdwardBrey's answer; that may have been implied in this answer, but I am dense and didn't see it.

Answer (score 7):

To listen on both the IPv4 and IPv6 stacks, use this code:

```
var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.IPv6Any, 2222);
listener.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, SocketOptionName.IPv6Only, false);
```

`IPv6Any` tells Windows to listen on the IPv6 stack. Setting the socket option to false tells Windows to not limit itself to the IPv6 stack, but rather to also listen on the IPv4 stack. The default is to only listen on the stack explicitly specified.

Comment: Same solution works for `System.Net.Sockets` `Socket.SetSocketOption` in dot net 4.0. In 4.5 simply use `TcpListener listener = TcpListener.Create(port);` as this is now the default behaviour see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/01/08/dual-mode-sockets-never-create-an-ipv4-socket-again.aspx

Comment: And mono 4.0 throws `Protocol option not supported` but this is probably resolved here: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-4.2.0-branch/mono/metadata/socket-io.c#L536